# 2 FK para uma 1 PK

Tags: mysql

Eu quero conectar as 2 FK da tabela cartão de credito e boleto bancário para a  tabela pagamento do ID_Pagamento mais o seguinte erro surge:

> Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-900_e'

[image: Modelagem das Tabelas]

não tenho idéia de como vai resolver,qualquer ajuda eu agradeço

```
CREATE TABLE `cartao_credito` (
  `ID_Cartao` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Numero_Cartao` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Codigo_Seguranca` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nome_Titular` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Validade_Mes` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Validade_Ano` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PagamentoID_Pagamento` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Cartao`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `boleto_bancario` (
  `ID_Boleto` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Cedente` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Agencia_Codigo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Numero_Documento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CPF_CNPJ` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Valor_Documento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Codigo_Boleto` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Codigo_Banco` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Vencimento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Documento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `N_Documento` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nosso_Numero` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PagamentoID_Pagamento` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Boleto`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `pagamento` (
  `ID_Pagamento` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Tipo_Pagamento` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PedidoID_Pedido` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Agenda_ServicoID_Agenda` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Pagamento`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Em que comando exatamente ocorre o erro?
Pode adicionar o comando para criação das FK?

Comment: 15:29:47 ALTER TABLE `prestadora`.`cartao_credito`  ADD CONSTRAINT `PagamentoID_Pagamento`   FOREIGN KEY (`PagamentoID_Pagamento`)   REFERENCES `prestadora`.`pagamento` (`ID_Pagamento`)   ON DELETE NO ACTION   ON UPDATE NO ACTION 

Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-900_e' 0.141 sec

Comment: sendo que eu fiz o mesmo na tabela do boleto e deu certo

Comment: Mas você colocou exatamente o mesmo nome na CONSTRAINT? Isto pode ser o problema.

Comment: e porque seria já que esta se referindo a mesma tabela ?

Comment: ALTER TABLE `prestadora`.`boleto_bancario` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `PagamentoID_Pagamento`
  FOREIGN KEY (`PagamentoID_Pagamento`)
  REFERENCES `prestadora`.`pagamento` (`ID_Pagamento`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente alterar o nome da constraint, conforme segue:

```
ALTER TABLE prestadora.cartao_credito ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pagamento 
FOREIGN KEY(PagamentoID_Pagamento) REFERENCES prestadora.pagamento (ID_Pagamento) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Conforme a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), o identificador da constraint deve ser único, do contrário será gerado um erro parecido com:

```
ERROR 1022 (2300): Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql- 464_1'
```

Opcionalmente o nome pode ser omitido, sendo gerado automaticamente pelo banco.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou direitinho então as FKs não podem ser iguais ?

Comment: @DouglasLopes Sim, mais detalhes na documentação em https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html.